# How does transaction chain work in MD-SAL?

Tags: opendaylight

As I understood from the previous post, each transaction has its snapshot merged to the data store in memory when the transaction is committed.
Does transaction chain have its own snapshot additional to the snapshots of each transaction within the chain? Are the transaction snapshots merged to the chain snapshot instead of the data store during the commit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All transactions are committed to the data store on submission. A chain adds semantics on top such that a transaction created from a chain observes the affects of prior submitted transactions created from the chain.